# Why i cant properly read arguments from activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

so im sending to ListFieldsFragment game id from activity, and its working
here is code from activity

```
class CreateFieldsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_fields)

        val intent = intent
        val gameId = intent.getIntExtra("game ID", 1)

        val mFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val mFragment = ListFieldsFragment()


        val mBundle = Bundle()
        mBundle.putInt("game ID", gameId)
        Log.d("gameid FieldsActivity", gameId.toString())
        mFragment.arguments = mBundle
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fields_ConstraintLayout, mFragment).commit()

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentFieldsContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentFieldsContainerView)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

then when i try to get it from arguments in my fragment it goes weird
here is the code from fragment

```
class ListFieldsFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mFieldViewModel: FieldViewModel
    private val adapter: ListFieldsAdapter by lazy { ListFieldsAdapter() }
    private var _binding: FragmentListFieldsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentListFieldsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        val recyclerView = binding.fieldsRecyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())


        val gameId = receiveGameId()

        Log.d("editgame1", gameId.toString())

        mFieldViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[FieldViewModel::class.java]
        mFieldViewModel.readGameWithFields(gameId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { field ->
            adapter.setData(field)
        })

        binding.fieldFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("action1", gameId.toString())
            val action =
                ListFieldsFragmentDirections.actionListFieldsFragmentToAddFieldFragment(
                    receiveGameId()
                )
            Log.d("action2", gameId.toString())
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }


        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.create_game_menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.search_item)
        val searchView = search?.actionView as? SearchView
        searchView?.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
    }



    private fun receiveGameId(): Int {
        return arguments?.getInt("game ID") ?: 1
    }
}
```

the problem is that logcat from editgame1 gives two values, one is always 1, and second is that matching value: 2, 3, etc.
here it is:

```
2024-01-27 18:43:58.910 13312-13312 editgame1         com.example.fiftygame                D  1
2024-01-27 18:43:58.925 13312-13312 editgame1         com.example.fiftygame                D  2
2024-01-27 18:44:01.467 13312-13312 editgame1         com.example.fiftygame                D  1
2024-01-27 18:44:01.482 13312-13312 editgame1         com.example.fiftygame                D  999
```

can you tell me where the problem is? why there are two values if i have only one tag with "editgame1"? is it refreshing twice? maybe something with navigation? i dont know what to do next. please help

Comment: i resolved the problem. my fragment was opening twice. i added graph for my app, so i navigate arguments between them, i dont use bundles/arguments